# Strange behaviour with UserHostAddress

Tags: c#, dns, asp.net-web-api, ip, iis-7.5

I have 3 WebApi Applications running with the following Setup

```
App1
Runs on Server1
Runs on IIS 7.5 on Site1 with a Fix IP .1

App2 
Runs on Server1
Runs on IIS 7.5 on Site2 with a Fix IP .2

App3
Runs on Server2
Runs on IIS 7.5 on Site3 with a Fix IP .3
```

All 3 Apps implement `AppX/Information` that returns the IP Adress. I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` for it.

When `App3` calls `App1/Information` or `App2/Information` I get back the IP `.3`, which is correct.

When `App1` calls `App2/Information` I get the IP `.2` instead of `.1`

Same goes for `App2` if it calls `App1/Information` I get the IP `.1` instead of `.2`

Does anyone has an explanation why I get the wrong IP? I guess it has something to do because App1 and App2 they are on the same server...?

**UPDATE**

```
appcmd list site
SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,net.tcp/808:*,net.pipe/*,net.msmq/localhost,msmq.formatname/localhost,state:Stopped)
SITE "App1" (id:2,bindings:https/161.20.134.49:443:,state:Started)
SITE "App2" (id:3,bindings:https/161.20.134.60:443:,state:Started)
SITE "AnotherApp" (id:4,bindings:https/161.20.134.59:443:,state:Started)


appcmd list app
APP "Default Web Site/" (applicationPool:DefaultAppPool)
APP "App1/" (applicationPool:MyApp Pool)
APP "App2/" (applicationPool:MyApp Pool)
APP "AnotherApp/" (applicationPool:AnotherApp Pool)
```

Comment: Can you run `appcmd list site` and `appcmd list app` and add the outcome to your question?

Comment: Can you run App1 and App2 in their own apppool instead of a shared one?

Comment: Yes I can try that. Will come back with an answer ASAP.

Comment: Still the same result :(

Answer (score 1):

`Request.UserHostAddress` internally returns the IIS server variable REMOTE_ADDR. So, answer to your question really depends on how IIS decides to populate this server variable based on the TCP connection made by the client. I do not know what IIS does but here is my guess. REMOTE_ADDR is nothing but the source IP of the network packet that reaches the server. This source IP depends on how the network packet gets routed to your server. My guess (and I'm very positive about this)  is that since App1 and App2 are in the same physical box, the request never had to go through the physical network card and becaue of this IIS can determine that the request comes from the same machine it runs on and hence it returns the IP associated with the binding. Check [this](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) out. When App3 calls App1 or App2, the request must go out of the network card and IIS gets the IP address of the client machine in that case.